# div from method is not rendering on the User Interface in react js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous

Im using react js and trying to access some dummy data from the holdingsByAccounts prop. The issue jsx is not rendering onto the screen when the page loads. Been looking into other ways and other sites that have some situation as this.  So my code is as follows:

```
  class PortDashSideBar extends Component {
              constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.oldPortfolioValue = 0;
              }
            
      getHoldingsForAccount = (id) => {
        this.props.holdingsByAccount.map((holding) => {
          return <span>{holding[id].value}</span>;
        });
      }
    
            
            
              renderConfigurations = () => {
                const {
                  classes,
                  accounts,
                  holdingsByAccount,
                  holdingsByAsset,
                  currentAccountId,
                  actions,
                  user
                } = this.props;
            
                const animationClassGreen = 'animateChangeGreen';
                const animationClassRed = 'animateChangeRed';
            
            
                
            
                return (
                  <Table className={classes.table} name="myConfigurations">
                    <TableBody style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                      {
                        accounts.map(account => (
                          <ButtonBase>
                            <TableRow
                              hover
                              name={account.name}
                              key={account.id}
                              onClick={() => { actions.updateAccount(account.id); }}>
                              <TableCell className={classes.cellBotIcon} />
                              <TableCell className={classes.cellName}>
                                <Typography className={classes.botName}>
                                  {account.label}
                                </Typography>
                                <Typography>
                                  <svg className={classes.svg}>
                                    <img src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AAUvwngo7rox3GTqcW5Omxr-UGXHwmGO4To3QDygqaYxpg=s900-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj" />
                                  </svg>
                                  <span className={classes.configName}>
                                    {this.getHoldingsForAccount(account.id)}
                                  </span>
                                </Typography>
                              </TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                          </ButtonBase>
            
                        ))
                      }
                    </TableBody>
                  </Table>
                );
              }
            
              render() {
                const {
                  classes
                } = this.props;
            
                return (
                  <Paper className={classes.paper} elevation={0} square >
                    <Grid container alignItems="center" justify="center">
                      <Grid className={classes.configurations} xs={12} item>
                        {this.renderConfigurations()}
                      </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                  </Paper>
                );
              }
            }
            
            PortDashSideBar.defaultProps = {
            };
            
            PortDashSideBar.propTypes = {
              actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
              classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
              accounts: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
              holdingsByAccount: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
              holdingsByAsset: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
              currentAccountId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
              user: PropTypes.object.isRequired
            };
            
            
            function mapStateToProps(state) {
              return {
                user: state.global.user.user,
                holdingsByAccount: state.holdings.holdings.byAccount,
                holdingsByAsset: state.holdings.holdings.byAsset,
                holdingsLoaded: state.holdings.holdings.holdingsLoaded,
                accounts: state.global.accounts.accounts,
                currentAccountId: state.trade.interactions.currentAccountId,
              };
            }
            
            function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
              return {
                actions: {
                  ...bindActionCreators({
                    updateAccount,
                  }, dispatch)
                }
              };
            }
            
            export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withStyles(styles)(PortDashSideBar));
```

Now, it is not showing error, but it is also not rendering on screen

Comment: Are you sure that every holding in `holdingsByAccount` has a value for every account in `accounts`?

Comment: Yep, I just checked

Comment: You need to change the getHoldingsForAccount method, you should find the record by the id, you're trying to find it by using the index, try this  this.props.holdingsByAccount.find(({id: holdingId }) => holdingId === id), with that result you can render the correct holding item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give you an answer, I think this is because you're trying to access the array item by the index, not by the item id, consider this:

```
const array = [1,2,3]
console.log(array[3])
// Prints undefined because the index starts in 0, so the index 3 should be the 4th item which does not exist in this array
```

So your example is trying to access an index that does not exist that is why is crashing. Also is worth to mention that your object id attribute is a string based on the image you upload, so if that string is not a number it will also fail:

```
const array = [1,2,3]
console.log(array["1"])
// Prints 2 because it parses the string to a number

const array = [1,2,3]
console.log(array["an-id"])
// Prints undefined because the string can't be parsed to a number
```

So to make things work, change the code to this:

```
getHoldingsForAccount = (id) => {
 // Use Array.find to find the item that matches the id parameter provided by the function
 const holding = this.props.holdingsByAccount.find((item) => item.id === id)

 // Returns the JSX only if the match was found.
 return holding && (
  <span>{holding.value}</span>
 )
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. The app is not crashing anymore, but for some reason, the div is not rendering on the user interface for some reason. Seems like everything is good to go except for the simple fact that its not rendering on the screen

Comment: How does it look the account array? can you post it?

Comment: Hey, I just edited the post to show the structure of it. Thanks

Comment: Are you returning the JSX in the getHoldingsForAccount? If so what happens if you console.log(holding) in that function

Comment: Thanks for your response again. I have updated the post to show the images of both the function, and the console of holding

Comment: It seems that you're using map, use the one that I put on the answer, because you don't need to map an array, you need the item in the array that matches with the id provided, you need to use find for that and if the match is found return the JSX with the <span>{holding.value}</span>

Comment: Ok, I used the one you provided. However, it when console logging the holding, it returns undefined

Comment: Jean! You were right! Turns out I had forgot to include the id where i was calling the method after changing to use your method. Thanks!